# linux 2.4 kernel source download

Tags: linux, download, linux-kernel

I am trying to find the linux 2.4 kernel source code.  It seems that it has been removed from the official download site and the mirrors.  This may have been result of the kernel.org compromise but it would be nice to have access to historical kernel source.  I have looked in the following directories on kernel.org and mirrors and found nothing:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/
http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/

Comment: Why do you specifically need to get 2.4 kernel source? I'm as surprised as you to not find them on kernel.org… It's maybe due to the recent outage.

Comment: I need the source for an academic exercise to compare various algorithms between the 2.4 kernel and 2.6 kernel.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google gave me very quickly [this uk mirror for linux 2.4](http://ftp.linux.org.uk/pub/linux/linux-2.4/)

but please explain why you want such an old version. Are you sure to have the hardware to run it???

Comment: Excellent.  Google was not so kind to me, I was looking for quite some time.  Thank you for your help.  As I explained above I needed the source code for an academic exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the kernel of 2.4.x from this URL: http://eduunix.ccut.edu.cn/index2/mirrors/kernel3/linux/kernel/v2.4/